# Data Studio: Calculate difference between two values of the the same varible based on different time ranges

Tags: looker-studio

We have a numerical variable in data studio in one column. Let's call this "average profit". We would like to calculate a new column in our data, which is the difference between the value of "average profit" for this current time range and the value of "average profit" compared to last month.
Which formula is best to use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to do that as a calculated field in Data Studio. You would have to do it as part of your data preparation.

Alternatively, as long as you have a month's worth of data selected, you could use "compare to previous period" to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Below Date Range you have the option to run Comparison Date Range. You can do it vs previous period.